# Invalid date issue using new Date()

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs, sencha-touch

I am passing timestamp to below function and it is returning me date string properly but when i am executing below line it is giving me error invalid date.

```
        var postDate = new Date(this.ConvertServerDateToLocal(timestamp));

 //postDate returns invalid date object.


        ConvertServerDateToLocal: function(dateInput){
            // EST - UTC offset: 4 hours

            var offset = 4.0,
            /*
             - calculate the difference between the server EST date and UTC
             - the value returned by the getTime method is the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC.
             - the time-zone offset is the difference, in minutes, between UTC and local time
             - 60000 milliseconds = 60 seconds = 1 minute
             */
                serverDate = new Date(dateInput),
                utc = serverDate.getTime() - (serverDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000),
             /*
             - apply the offset between UTC and EST (4 hours)
             - 3600000 milliseconds = 3600 seconds = 60 minutes = 1 hour
             */
             clientDate = new Date(utc + (3600000 * offset));
            return clientDate.toLocaleString();
        }
```

Below is example timestamp i am passing to ConvertServerDateToLocal() function.

timestamp = "Nov 22, 2017 23:05:58"   // Throwing invalid date after output

timestamp = "Nov 09, 2017 18:30:19"   // Working properly

Answer (score 0):

```
function ConvertServerDateToLocal(dateInput) {
    // EST - UTC offset: 4 hours
    dateInput = "Nov 09, 2017 18:30:19";
    var offset = 4.0,
    /*
     - calculate the difference between the server EST date and UTC
     - the value returned by the getTime method is the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC.
     - the time-zone offset is the difference, in minutes, between UTC and local time
     - 60000 milliseconds = 60 seconds = 1 minute
     */
    serverDate = new Date(dateInput.toString());

    utc = serverDate.getTime() - (serverDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);

    /*
    - apply the offset between UTC and EST (4 hours)
    - 3600000 milliseconds = 3600 seconds = 60 minutes = 1 hour
     */
    clientDate = new Date(utc + (3600000 * offset));

    //return clientDate.toLocaleString();
    alert(clientDate.toLocaleString());
}
```

Converting the input paramter to string worked for me. But I am not sure why one date worked and the other didn't work. If you found the answer, please post it here. I also use Dates a lot and they are always a pain.